# Git server side hooks get file changes

Tags: git, api, gitlab, hook

I have an 2 api endpoints like this http://someserver.com/createFile

and http://someserver.com/updateFile

that takes a post request with file content, parses it and create and updates the file on the server

the request in nothing fancy its just a RAW post request

so now I would like that when file is commited on git (I am using Gitlab if it matters), it would take the file content and call http://someserver.com/createFile

and another hook that would only take commit changes and call http://someserver.com/updateFile

Don't realy have any idea how I would do that if its even possible (I would realy like to avoid a cronJob that would pull from git every second and get file changes that way, so hooks seam a prety good idea)

Thanks for Anwsering

Comment: Hosting systems (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket) have notification systems that will tell you when commits are added to repositories you control. Each one has a *different* system, though, so it does matter. You'll want to look into whatever notifications GitLab offer. Note that you won't get notifications when anyone commits somewhere, only when something interesting happens *on GitLab* (everyone who clones has *their own private repository*).

Comment: I guess I would only need to know when someone commits and pushes something to gitlab (don't care for local commits), so I would get what has changed (or if this is not possible at least the whole content of a file that changed)

Comment: OK, you probably want to look into the GitLab APIs and notifications, then.